# Datatables 1.10 - Swap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my application I have table that can have multiple columns, based on date range selected.
I need to be able to display table containing 20 columns or 50 columns (number of columns is based on data range from parameters). I did that, but I was refreshing page when my parameters changed.
Now I'm trying to do it better.

I've created sample that shows my approach: http://live.datatables.net/fojusec/3

Basically I'm swapping "table" with new content that comes from ajax request and then I'm calling "dataTable" on that new table.
My example works fine, but I was wondering if maybe there is a better way to do it, maybe by reconfiguring table?

Is it safe to do that like I did it? I'm worried about any leaks.

**EDIT:**
What I'm not sure is if dataTable object is attached to table. So if I'm removing table from DOM should I be removing dataTable object also.
I would like to avoid any conflicts. I clicked on my example for some time and I didn't got any errors.

**QUESTION:** What is the best way to swap or reconfigure table using datatables 1.10

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, initially you lost the setting between 20 or 50 columns and you want to save it?

Comment: No, what I'm trying to do is to change number of columns dynamically. If I select date range to 12 months then I need 12 columns, if I select 30 months then 30 columns. table content is generated by webservice (in my sample buttons on top simulate ajax call). My problem is how I should I delete (destroy) old datatable and create new - I don't want any old object left. Right now I'm changing content of DIV and calling datatables on new table (that comes from my webservice). But I would like to do it better (if it is possible)

Comment: You could render the table with max columns and then hide (or show) part of them depending on your date range. That way you would only have 1 request to server instead of multiple. This should help: http://www.datatables.net/extras/colvis/

Comment: I must do server request every time I need new data for table, because each column presents percentage value of total (sum of value on each columns is equal to 100%). If I'll need 200 columns only ones for a while I should always have 200 columns? This isn't a good solution.